# Ugly combination of generator expression with for loop

Tags: python, for-loop, generator

The following appears in my Python 2.6 code:

```
for src, dst in ([s,d] for s in universe for d in universe if s != d):
```

Can I do much better? What I particularly don't like is that I'm in effect specifying the same pair twice, once for the for loop and again for the generator expression. I'm uncertain whether I'd prefer:

```
for src, dst in itertools.product(universe, universe):
    if src != dst:
```

Is there a way to express this loop concisely?

`universe` happens to be a list, if it makes any difference. Order of iteration doesn't matter.

Comment: What sort of routine requires/allows a cross product like this?

Comment: I think your code is nice, the first example is clearer to understand than the other.

Comment: @Ignacio: I'm constructing a 2-way graph whose nodes are the elements of `universe`, and which will be processed by some other piece of software elsewhere that expects a set of edges. I have code to calculate the existence and weight of each edge: if it helps you can assume this is a function `make_edge(src, dst)`, which returns a description. Solutions which use `map` or other related functions to call `make_edge` are plausible, and perhaps the right thing to do, but turning the body of the for loop into a function is no less repetition than I have already, so doesn't fix that niggle AFAIK.

Comment: Yes, I'd vote for the second version too. Looks pretty readable and clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use simple nested for-loops:

```
for src in universe:
   for dst in universe:
      if src == dst:
         continue
      ...
```

I'd say this is the most easy to read syntax in this case.

Comment: You may well be right. I hate it when the purely imperative code is the simplest ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I suggest keeping it entirely functional or entirely with comprehensions. Here's an implementation that's entirely functional.

```
import itertools 
import operator

def inner_product(iterable):
    "the product of an iterable with itself"
    return itertools.product(iterable, repeat=2)

def same(pair):
    "does this pair contain two of the same thing?"
    return operator.is_(*pair)

universe = 'abcd'

pairs = inner_product(universe)
unique_pairs = itertools.ifilterfalse(same, pairs)
for pair in unique_pairs:
    print pair

"""
('a', 'b')
('a', 'c')
('a', 'd')
('b', 'a')
('b', 'c')
('b', 'd')
('c', 'a')
('c', 'b')
('c', 'd')
('d', 'a')
('d', 'b')
('d', 'c')
"""
```

Comment: I like this in principle. In practice, the code might be maintained by people who don't/barely know Python, so I don't think I dare actually use it this time.

Answer (score 1):

itertools.product can take a "repeat" keyword argument if you want to have the same sequence as more than one parameter:

```
itertools.product(universe, repeat=2)
```

it is a matter of opinion as to whether this is more readable.

You could replace your original code with:

```
for (src, dest) in filter(lambda (a,b): a!=b, itertools.product(universe, repeat=2)):
    ...
```

Comment: Nice. I didn't know you could do that.

Comment: As you're using a `filter` with a `lambda`, it doesn't cost much more to do `for (src, dest) in ((a,b) for a,b in itertools.product(universe, repeat=2) if a != b):`. **NOTE:** Which does the same. Yes. My point is letting OP decide which is the most readable.